# Where do custom model fields get converted to their db_type?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I'm a bit confused here.

I wrote a custom model field called `PriceField` that returns an instance of my class `Price` from its `from_db_value` and `to_python` methods, which both convert from strings to instances of `Price`.

My `db_type` method returns `"string"` because I want values of the field to be represented as strings in the database.

When I go to add a model that contains a `PriceField` to the database, I'm getting `InterfaceError: binding parameter 3`. The `params` value for the sql statement is

```
[1,
 'test',
 'desc',
 <utils.Price object at 0x7f159d9e6da0>,
 '2019-02-22 00:39:31.634898',
 'FS',
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 '',
 '']
```

I'm pretty sure that `<utils.Price object at 0x7f159d9e6da0>` is my problem- how do I get that converted to a string so the database can accept it? I already have `__str__` methods for my `Price` and `PriceField` classes.

Here are my 2 classes:

```
class Price():
    units = None
    value = 0

    def __init__(self, units, value):
        if not type(units) is PaymentUnit:
            # TODO: Throw the right exception here
            return;

        self.units = units;
        self.value = value;


    def __str__(self):
        return self.units.symbol + str(self.value)



class PriceField(models.Field):
    units = '⧫'
    value = 1

    def __init__(self, value = 1, units='⧫', *args, **kwargs):         

         self.value = value;
         self.units = units;

        # Pass the values to the super class constructor

         # Up to 16 digits, plus a decimal and up to 8 decimal
         # digits (0.00000001 BTC is 1 satoshi)
         kwargs['max_length'] = 24;

         kwargs['help_text'] = 'Represents a price in a specific currency.';

         kwargs['default'] = '⧫1'

         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
         name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()         
         del kwargs['max_length']

         if self.units != '⧫':
             kwargs['units'] = self.units

         if self.value != 1:
             kwargs['value'] = self.value

         return name, path, args, kwargs

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'string'

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return None
        return parse_price(value);


    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Price):
            return value
        elif value is None:
            return None
        else:
            return parse_price(value)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}{1}".format(self.units.symbol, self.value)
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Sure, what code would you like to see? I'm not super clear on what parts of my classes are used for what.

Comment: Did you follow the [guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/)? Show us your model class

Comment: Yes, I did follow that. I just edited my 2 classes in to the question.

Comment: Does your database accepts `string` as a valid type? Also you might want to override `get_prep_value`

Comment: Yes, I'm using strings in other models. But Django isn't passing my `Price` instance to the database as a string, it's passing it as a raw type.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your edit. It looks like `get_prep_value` was all I needed. Not sure how I missed that in the guide. Thank you. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it correct.